# How to pass a generic parameter to schedular "thread" function in Java?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, generics

I need to pass T parameter to scheduleAtFixedRate and it gives an error *

> "Required Type: Runnable, Provided: T"
> *

my code:

```
@Autowired
private ScheduledExecutorService executerService;

public void submitTask(T myTask)
{
   executerService.scheduleAtFixedRate(myTask, 0, propertiesCache.getRefreshRate(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

Comment: I don't know where `T` is defined, but the `ScheduledExecutorService` requires its jobs to be of type `Runnable` or `Callable<X>` for some `X`. Which one depends on the method. Can you try binding the definition of `T` to `<T extends Runnable>`?

Comment: Yes...Thank you so much, "extends runnable" in the definition of T was missing.